# Pass namespace to an included xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I work with two file transformations. The main file contains an import statement in his second transformation file. My second transform file contains several templates that are generic to all my transformations. My problem is that all my transformations not the same data namespace. I wish I could get the namespace to use in my second transform.

XSLT1 :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:n="http://novamap.fr/xml/data/v1/XmlModelBonDeCommande" version="1.0">

  <xsl:include href="Common.xslt"/>

  <xsl:template match="/n:XmlModelBonDeCommande">
  ......
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT2 :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:n="http://novamap.fr/xml/data/v1/XmlModelEtatDesLieux" version="1.0">

  <xsl:include href="Common.xslt"/>

  <xsl:template match="/n:XmlModelEtatDesLieux">
  ......
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Common.xslt :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:n="<--my problem-->" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template name="doc1">
    <xsl:value-of select="n:VALUE1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="doc2">
    <xsl:value-of select="n:VALUE2"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to pass the namespace to use to Common.xslt from XSLT1 and XSLT2 files

Answer (score 1):

You would need to declare two namespace in the included document and write code to match or select elements in two namespace e.g. instead of `<xsl:value-of select="n:VALUE1"/>` you would use `<xsl:value-of select="n1:VALUE1 | n2:VALUE1"/>` or better yet you would change stuff like

```
  <xsl:template name="doc1">
    <xsl:value-of select="n:VALUE1"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

to

```
  <xsl:template match="n1:VALUE1 | n2:VALUE1">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
```

A different approach would be to use a separate stylesheet or separate transformation step that first normalizes the XML input documents to a single namespace.

Comment: Thank, yes it is a solution, but I have a lot of files transformations. It is not possible to have the n from a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I found an other solution

```
<xsl:variable name="namespace" select="'<your namespace>'" />

<xsl:template name="doc1">
    <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='VALUE1' and namespace-uri()=$namespace]"/>
</xsl:template>
```